# understanding effect of jquery statement

Tags: jquery

I was looking for an easy way to get the contents of a jquery element and came across this page:  http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/how-to-get-full-html-string-including.html

It has the following code

```
var html = $('<div>').append($('#top').clone()).remove().html();
```

Their explanation is as follows:

> 1) Cloning selected div
>
> 2) Creating a new div DOM object and appending created clone of the div
>
> 3) Then getting the contents of wrapped div (which would give us all HTML)
>
> 4) Finally removing the created DOM object, so it does not clutter our DOM tree.

My question are as follows:
1) it looks like the first thing this does is create a *new* div that is not attached to the dom, so why does it need to have the "remove" call?
2) I understand why it doesn't come up for this example, but in general is there much difference between doing

```
A:  $('<div>').append('<span>foobar</span>') 
B:  $('<div><span>foobar</span></div>)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order, it does this:

1. Create a new empty DIV object (not in the DOM yet)
2. Find the "#top" object in your page
3. Clone that "#top" object.
4. Append this clone to the previously created DIV object
5. Remove the whole DIV object from the DOM and clean up any jQuery related data to any of the objects
6. Get the innerHTML of the DIV object

The one thing that the `.remove()` does here is clean up any jQuery data associated with any objects in the tree that wouldn't otherwise happen at this point.

In your examples A and B, there is technically not supposed to be a difference between the two.  In practice, I've found a few bugs in older versions of IE with option B.  jQuery seems to follow a code path involving document fragments and I've seen some problems with that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a jQuery expert, but after messing with WebKit's Web Inspector with the code you mentioned, it seems that you're right: remove() isn't necessary as the returned variable isn't added to the DOM and doesn't even seem to be a jQuery object.

As for part 2), the only difference I would think is part A is creating an element and using a DOM innerHTML and appendChild call, whereas part B is just creating an element and doing an innerHTML call.. haven't looked at the jQuery source but that's my guess.  Performance-wise it doesn't make a difference with small strings as those, but I prefer the readability of A.